# Uploading HUGE file to VPS server

Tags: file-upload, file-transfer

I have a huge file (50Gb) that is an entire back-up of a website that I am trying to upload to a server via FTP (FileZilla) and the entire process drops sometimes after 80% completion!

I also have a 20Mbps upload speed via my ISP, but Filezilla will only let me upload at 1.5mbps.  Why is this and how can I utilize more speed of the upload connection?

Someone told me to go to a DataCenter and upload the back-up file, but I have never heard of such.

Thanks for your time,

An Obvious Noob

Answer (score 0):

FTP can fail on large uploads for a variety of reasons - what error message are you getting?

There are lots of reasons that you might only be uploading at 1.5 mbps:
1. Your network provider is capping your bandwidth. (You can test upload speeds at speedtest.net).

2. The latency between your computer and your datacenter is too high. You can find the latency by pinging the destination server or running a traceroute to it.

Often companies with files that large will use UDP based file transfer services to move their files online.